# How to convert a pandas series to a list of items?

Tags: python, pandas, list

[image]

I have a data frame that one of its columns has a list of IDs. I want to work with this column as a list, But whatever I do it doesn't happen and Python sees that as a string of characters. One row of the column is like this:
`[xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa, bbb, ccc]`
and for every rows, It's like that. I want to get the length of this row as 5, but I get 30! I want to write a condition to select a subset of a data frame from that column, like:
`df1 = df[len(df["IDs"])>5]`

How can I do that? I'm new to Python and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: They are not truly lists but strings then. You can try `import ast; df.IDs = df.IDs.apply(ast.literal_eval)` to make them lists.

Comment: can you please show some of your data or ```DataFrame```? if your dataframe has stored the data you desired, you can get a ```column``` from your dataframe as a list with the [```to_list()```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) method: ```df['ID'].to_list()```

Comment: @MustafaAydın thank you so much. I tried that too but I get this error:

ValueError: malformed node or string

Comment: then use `df['IDs']=df['IDs'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')`?

Comment: @99_m4n thank you so much. I tried that, but it creates a list for all the rows, I want each row to have a list of IDs. I edited the post to add an image of the dataframe. I want to cut the rows in which their list of IDs has a length less than 5.

Comment: @AnuragDabas thank you so much. The dtype before doing anything is "object". Should I convert it to string, then use this command to make the list?

Comment: IIUC then If you want the length of elements inside each row and check the length of elements then you can do `mask=df['IDs'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str.len().gt(5)` then finally pass this mask to your dataframe for filter that rows i.e `result=df[mask]` or `result=df.loc[mask]`

Comment: @Elahe Then you can cast entirely to `str` first, this might work: `df.IDs = df.IDs.astype(str).apply(literal_eval)`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın it worked! thanks a lot. I just used astype(str), then used a mask.